# Closed launchd in OS X, the screen is now blank

Tags: mac

I have a 2 year old Mac book running whatever the newer OS X is. For some reason I was playing in activity manager and deleted launchd and now I'm just looking at a blank screen and my computer won't even shut down. Please help?

Comment: Well, you didn't actually delete launchd, you just stopped its process. The launchd you killed was probably the parent process of everything running in your user account--so you did the equivalent of a force-logout, but loginwindow was never informed to give you a new login screen. Everything will return as normal when you reboot as Spiff instructs.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the power button for 10 full seconds.

If somehow that doesn't shut it down, just pull the power (both the AC power adapter and the battery, if your model has an externally removable battery).